# How to rewrite URL in multi-lingual ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL in my asp.net multi-lingual web site using Web.config with rule section.

I have urls like: 
`http://example.com/lang/en/index.html`, `http://example.com/lang/fr/index.html`, etc

I need to remove `lang` and `.html` extension and rewrite url to: 
`http://example.com/en/index`, `http://example.com/fr/index`

My Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteHTML">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
        </rule> 
    <rule name="Rewrite friendly URLs to phsyical paths">
     <match url="^(.*)$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="lang/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

So If I go 'http://example.com/en/index' I need to open this page: 'http://example.com/lang/en/index.html'.

How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]
Finally it is solved. Here is Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="On" />
  </system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Ignore" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(js|css).*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect requests to friendly URLs">
          <match url="^(.*?)/(.*)\.html$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite friendly URLs to phsyical paths">
         <match url="^\/(?!#.*).*" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="lang/{R:0}.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Special thanks to Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani for "Ignore" part (is needed to ignore: javaScript, Images and CSS folders to keep the links working)

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="the name" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="example.com/(.+)(?:/(.+)?)(.html)?"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="lang/{R:1}/{R:2}.html"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I tried if I open http://example.com/en/index - "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

Comment: does the address change as you wanted? I don't know where example.com/en/index redirects what I can help you (and you asked for) is to rewrite example.com/lang/en/index to example.com/en/index

Comment: No it does not. This path: "/lang/en/index.html" it is physical folder and file path. I need just to hide 'lang' and '.html'. So If I go 'http://example.com/en/index' it should open this 'http://example.com/lang/en/index.html'

Comment: If I go 'example.com/en/index' or 'example.com/en/index.html' - "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

Comment: could you please tell me the real domain name so I can see it myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78054/discussion-between-user3314998-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani).